# MapStore implemenation

Tags: hazelcast

I would like to know do I need to have the mapstore implementation across all the hazelcast servers or only 1 is enough?

for example, I have 4 hazelcast servers. if I set the same mapstore in all 4 servers does this means all 4 hazelcast servers will execute the same logic 4 times for the same key? (There is no clear documentation mention this ).

Another case, if I call imap.put(k,v), will all 4 hazelcast servers call the load(key) method at the same time or only 1 server will handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sertug, I got your point. But what about if I also implement the interface `MapLoaderLifecycleSupport` will the `init` method is called by all members as well? Map store name I set to `*`

Comment: You need to add your `MapLoaderLifecycleSupport` to each members classpath. They will be called locally on each member.

Answer (score 3):

When using an IMap, your data is sharded and distributed to cluster members. Those shards can have backups in different members too. Please take a look at the related section [of the docs](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#data-partitioning).

So a specific key will be stored on only one of the members, hence only that member's store() implementation will be triggered.

This also means you need to set the MapStore implementation in all members.